# Is the smallest singular value able to measure the similarity between two matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I came across an interesting statement.

Given two matrices $A$ and $B$, with orthogonal unit column vectors of the same length. $A$ and $B$ are not necessarily square matrices. One would use $\sigma_p(A^TB)$ to measure the similarity between $A$ and $B$. [$\sigma_p(X)$ is the smallest singular value of $X$].

Moreover, if the column space of $A$ is a subspace of the column space of $B$ (${\rm span}\,A \subseteq{\rm span}\,B$), then $\sigma_p(A^TB)=1$.

I can show that $\sigma_p(A^TB)=1$ when ${\rm span}\,A\subseteq{\rm span}B$. But I have a few more questions.

The first one is: if $A\notin{\rm span}B$, do we have $\sigma_p(A^TB)<1$?

The second one is: will we have the same conclusion when $A$ and $B$ are two arbitrary matrices?

Comment: Please clarify in your question the followings: (a) whether $A,B$ are square matrices, (b) what does $\operatorname{span}\,B$ means (a unit multiple of $B$, the column space of $A$ is a subspace of the column space of $B$, etc.).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. (a) $A$ and $B$ are not necessarily square matrices. (b) span $B$ means the column space of $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably $A$ and $B$ are real matrices. Also, $A$ has fewer columns than, or the same number of columns as, $B$.

The answer to your first question is affirmative. Let $A$ has $p$ columns. Then $A^TB$ has $p$ singular values. As each of $A$ and $B$ has orthonormal column vectors, by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, all rows of $C=A^TB$ have norms bounded above by $1$. Furthermore, as $\operatorname{col}(A)\not\subseteq\operatorname{col}(B)$, *some* row of $C$ has norm strictly smaller than $1$. Therefore the $\operatorname{trace}(CC^T)<p$. Yet, $\operatorname{trace}(CC^T)=\sum_{i=1}^p\sigma_i(C)^2$. Therefore $\sigma_p(C)<1$.

For your second question, I suppose that by "arbitrary" matrices, you mean those with *unit* column vectors that are not necessarily mutually orthogonal. Then the answer is negative. For a counterexample, let $A=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1\\ 1}$ and $B=\frac1{\sqrt{5}}\pmatrix{2&2\\ 1&1}$. The only singular value of $A^TB$ is then $\frac3{\sqrt{5}}\approx1.3416>1$.